# Subversion 'forgets' to commit class files and view files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application and using Visual Studio, TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN. When I try  to commit my project to the Subversion server, all except the class (.cs) and view (.cshtml) files are committed. Is there a reason why Subversion prefers to forget to commit these files?

Comment: what does `svn status` tell you about these files?

Comment: Probably they are new and unversioned. You need to add them to SVN version control or when your commiting, check the option "Show unversioned files" and then select the new files you want to commit.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion does not automatically add files for committing. Some clients integrated with IDEs may do so as a convenience feature, but the standard SVN behavior is to *not* do this.

In Windows Explorer, check via TortoiseSVN to see if the items have been added. If not, do so (right-click, TortoiseSVN, Add), then commit.